# Applying CSS to PHP pages included using PHP include() or require()

Tags: php, css, include, require

If certain parts of a page, for example headers, footers and navigation bars, are included (require()) into a page, but have their own formatting, is there a way to make a stylesheet which applies only to to the included part, and not to the rest of the page? I understand that server-side include functions operate server-side, and CSS is read client-side, so there is most likely no direct way to do this, but any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking, is not possible. 
To achieve such thing, you would need to change your CSS.

For example, if you have:

```
.foo {
  // Css...
}
```

You should do:

```
#container .foo {
  // Css
}
```

Where `container` is the ID of a warpping element on you naviagtaion bar, header, footer or whatever you want to have it's own CSS.

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Not a bad idea, make a wrapping container for everything on the included page, and then specify that in the CSS. It seems it would cut performance somewhat, though.

Comment: I am sure it would not be a huge performance problem. In fact, you would be reducing the search area for your CSS rules.